# What token type is ETH on the Polygon network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, erc20

I am looking to work with ETH tokens on the Polygon network. My aim is to build a simple payment splitting application. Primarily to split royalties from Opensea. The issue I have come across is that Opensea doesn't seem to pay royalties in Matic token, instead, royalties are paid in ETH (plus other tokens).

I understand how to handle the network native, Matic, as well as ERC20 tokens. My main question is, what token type is ETH on the Polygon network? Is it an ERC20 (or similar) used to represent ETH on Polygon or does it have a special token type and privileges by virtue of Polygon being a layer two solution for Ethereum?

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, I tried to find answers online but because of the keywords all of the results were about bridging ETH to Polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensea uses [WETH](https://polygonscan.com/token/0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619) token on Polygon, which is an ERC-20 token representing the Ethereum mainnet ETH.

> *Please note, the "purple" Polygon ETH you see on OpenSea, is actually WETH (Wrapped Ether) on the blockchain level of Polygon.*

Source: https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/4403264773523-How-do-I-find-my-funds-on-Polygon-

Comment: OpenSea is very incorrect. There is no wrapped ETH on Polygon, because there is no ETH in the first place. You cannot wrap something that does not exist. You only have the bridged token.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Interesting. Can you clarify what do you mean by "no ETH in the first place"? Am I correct in assuming that your comment is more about the fundamentals (rather than the technical description of the wrapped/bridged token) and could say the same about the WBTC token on Ethereum, as there is no real BTC on the Ethereum network? Even though there is an entity holding a portion of the BTC amount that the WBTC tokens represent, and I do agree that it's not the real BTC.

Comment: There are multiple bridged BTC tokens on Ethereum network: WBTC, renBTC, tBTC. None of them is wrapped in a sense that you are guaranteed to be able  to unwrap and it get BTC.

Answer (score 1):

ETH on the Polygon network is ERC-20 compatible token. Ethereum does not really exist on Matic, it is bridged there [over a custodial Matic bridge](https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/getting-started/), so the security guarantees won't be the same.